# Update build variable using powershell in tfs

Tags: powershell, tfs, continuous-integration

I'm using Visual Studio TFS Services and want to run a powershell, update a variable and use it in another task.

My build definition only has 2 powershell tasks and 1 variable (NugetEnabled) with default value "dontpush".

**Build variables**: NugetEnabled (value: "dontpush")

**Task 1:** Powershell Script

```bsh
##vso[task.setvariable variable=NugetEnabled;]push
```

**Task 2:** Powershell Script

```bsh
$value= $env:NugetEnabled

if ($value)
{
    Write-Output "Value of the nuget is set and equals to $value"
}
else
{
    Write-Output "Value of the nuget doesn't exists."
}
```

The output console writes:

```sh
"Value of the nuget is set and equals to dontpush"
```

Expected value: "push".

I'm not able to update the value. I want to update the value because I want to use a "Custom condition" to push my nuget package.

The complete powershell script [is hosted in github](https://github.com/huchim/reporting-csv/blob/master/nuget-version.ps1) and my agent version is `2.116.1`

Thanks in advance!
Any advice will be apreciated and useful.

Comment: I change the comand with `Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=NugetEnabled;]push")` and works perfect!...

Answer (score 1):

In fact, i'm using TFS 2017 and library for powershell vsts task :

github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/tree/master/powershell

So, it becomes really simple to use variable shared between build/release Task.

Example (importing the ps module) :

```
$Script_Path = $PSScriptRoot
Import-Module $script_Path"\VstsTaskSdk\VstsTaskSdk.psd1" -force #2>&1> $null

$Root_Path =  $ENV:ROOT_PATH
$Repo_Path = $ENV:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY
$Repo_Branch = $ENV:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME
$Repo_CID = $ENV:BUILD_CID
$Log_Folder = $ENV:LOG_FOLDER
$SCRIPT_DB = $ENV:SCRIPT_DB
$Build_result_folder = $ENV:BUILD_RESULT_FOLDER



$Artifact_Path=$ENV:BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY
write-host "Artifact_Path : "$($Artifact_Path)  -backgroundcolor "Red"

$File_Log = $Log_Folder+"\LOG-TFS-"+$ENV:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER+".log"
Write-Host "Fichier de log : "$FileLog -backgroundcolor "Red"
Set-VstsTaskVariable -Name "LOG_FILE" -Value $File_Log  #2>&1> $null
```

To set variable value : Set-VstsTaskVariable

To get variable value : Get-VstsTaskVariable

To get variable value, as well, you can use the environment variable automatically exported by TFS, the naming convention for build-in variable change when use in ps script, there is to convert the name "." to "_".

example : $ENV:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME become Build.SourceNameBranche in TFS UI interface.
Otherwise, define your own variable in TFS and use it in PS as my example, $ENV:...
without naming conversion.

Build Variable details : https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables

Release Variable details : https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/definitions/release/variables